# how to create plots with exact units and measurements

Tags: python, linux, matplotlib, plot, latex

I am preparing an activity for a college math class which I'd like to use while introducing integration to students. They will be given some function and a plot of this function. Then they are going to calculate the definite integral and using a pair of scissors, cut out the area under the curve. On a scale they will weigh this piece of paper, divide the value on the display by the specific paper density and compare the result with the value computed earlier. For the task to work it is important that 1 unit in the plot will be 1 actual centimeter.

I have tried to do this with matplotlib and latex. But it doesn't quite work. First I generate a plot using the following python code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def cm2inches(value):
    inch = 2.54
    return value/inch

plt.ioff()
#Direct input 
plt.rcParams['text.latex.preamble']=[r"\usepackage{lmodern}"]
#Options
params = {'text.usetex' : True,
          'font.size' : 10,
          'font.family' : 'lmodern',
          'text.latex.unicode': True,
          }
plt.rcParams.update(params) 


def f(x):
    return x*x

h = 0.01
x_min = 0.0
x_max = 21.0
X = np.arange(x_min,x_max,h)
Y = f(X)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.xlabel(r'$x$')
plt.ylabel(r'$y$')
ratio = 400./400    #height/width
fig.set_size_inches(cm2inches(x_max),cm2inches(x_max*ratio)) 
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(width=0.3)
ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(width=0.3)
for axis in ['top','bottom','left','right']:
    ax.spines[axis].set_linewidth(0.3)   
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0,right=1,top=1,left=0,wspace=0,hspace=0)
plt.axis([x_min,x_max,x_min,x_max])
plt.plot(X,Y,alpha=0.7,lw=0.5)
plt.grid(lw=0.2)
plt.savefig('0.pdf')
fig = plt.close()
```

The file 0.pdf is 210mm x 210mm large. Then I try to import this file into my latex document:

```
\documentclass[A4,pdftex,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[total={210mm,296mm},top=1.6cm,bottom=1cm,left=0cm,right=0cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

  \begin{figure}[H]
      \includegraphics{0}
  \end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Now it should be exactly 21 cm wide. But there is a gap on the right. What can I do to make this work? Do I have to change dpi?

Comment: Is this a problem in the latex rendering or python's display (i.e. is it correct if you just display it)? Alternatively, have you tried just using a jupyter notebook and [including the latex in a code cell directly](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/2.x/examples/Notebook/Display%20System.ipynb#LaTeX) as this may make it easier to play around with the size attributes?

Comment: I need to print an A4 page and on this page there should be the diagram in the correct scaling. I'd like to make the above code work because I already invested so much time.

Comment: okay, the question I am asking is does the image display at the correct size if we remove latex (and this is a latex rendering issue, which I suspect) or it doesn't display correctly and this is an issue with the Python code (don't answer in a comment just edit your question to include this information)

Comment: it must be the rendering. I added the information in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it! See [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66439/wrong-a4-measurements) thread. In the code above I changed

```
\documentclass[a4paper,pdftex,10pt]{article}
```